# RabbitMQ.Client Faild to consume the messages shoveled from Azure Service Bus

Tags: rabbitmq, azureservicebus, rabbitmq-shovel

### I have a .net application to connect to RabbitMQ with RabbitMQ.Client 6.4.0.
The messages are shoveled from Azure Service Bus.
The RabbitMQ.Client throw the following exception.  But, if the message is sent from RabbitMQ UI, or RabbitMQ.Client itself. there is no problem.
The code is in https://github.com/wjmirror/HiBunny
The shovel is from Azure Service Bus, topic portal.quoterequests to rabbitmq exchange portal.quoterequests.

RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=541, text='INTERNAL_ERROR', classId=0, methodId=0
at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SimpleBlockingRpcContinuation.GetReply(TimeSpan timeout)
at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.BasicConsume(String queue, Boolean autoAck, String consumerTag, Boolean noLocal, Boolean exclusive, IDictionary`2 arguments, IBasicConsumer consumer) at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.AutorecoveringModel.BasicConsume(String queue, Boolean autoAck, String consumerTag, Boolean noLocal, Boolean exclusive, IDictionary`2 arguments, IBasicConsumer consumer)
at RabbitMQ.Client.IModelExensions.BasicConsume(IModel model, String queue, Boolean autoAck, IBasicConsumer consumer)
at HiBunny.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\study\HiBunny\HiBunny\Program.cs:line 64

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I had the exact same issue with a shovel I just setup from an Azure Service Bus and after spending almost a week trying to find an answer this was my solution.

The issue for me was in RabbitMQ itself. I was sending the messages to a fanout exchange to route to multiple endpoints but each time a message came through it would break all the connections with an internal error.

The solution was basically when adding the shovel even though fanout doesn't support routing you need to add a * as the routing key to the exchange in RabbitMQ. This then just started to work so I believe it's a bug that might of been fixed in newer versions.

I'm using RabbitMQ v3.10.6

I hope this helps someone in the future as this was a really struggle to find out that it was such an easy fix!